# Match only the first letter in a string in Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

How do you return a match for facets that begin with a certain letter? For instance, Elasticsearch suggests you use the query `"T*"` to return all titles that begin with the letter T. However, this seems to return titles that contain any words that begin with the letter T. For example, "Trees and Shrubs" as well as "How to Prune Trees." I only want to return "Trees and Shrubs". I tried using `"^T*"`, but that returns SearchPhraseExecutionException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, elasticsearch **analyzes** the fields using the **default analyzer**, which splits the field up into tokens split generally on English-language word boundaries.  So "How to Prune Trees" gets split into ("How", "to", "Prune", "Trees") and the token "Trees" subsequently matches your query, "T*".  To avoid this, you have to specify that the field is `not_analyzed` in the object [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/).  This makes elasticsearch effectively treat the field value as one giant token, which it will then match correctly against your prefix query.

You might also check out the [prefix query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/prefix-query/), but this is effectively just another way of issuing the same query.  You still need to specify that the field is not analyzed in the mapping.

Comment: I used a lot of not_analyzed fields and ran into capitalization problems (like t != T). A keyword analyser + a lowercase filter should take care of that, too.